# wordpress custom taxonomies divider

Tags: html, css, wordpress

So I have set up a theme with a lot of custom taxonomies and want to know if there is a way to close all dividers from within that meta box so when an editor posts text inside that meta box and does not close all  for that not to interfere with rest of page.

Example:

```
backend:
<div class="container"><?php the_field('XXXX'); ?></div>

frontend:
<div><h1> ths is this heading</h1><div><p> this is the text</p></div>
```

where there is only ONE  inside the box rather than two, mistake from user.
What can I do so it does not interfere with the rest of code?

I thought 'clear:both' was it but that only cancels out the float bars.

Thanks for any help please!

Answer (score 0):

WordPress features some handy formatting functions to balance tags:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/balanceTags
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/force_balance_tags

To be applied to the user input when saving to the database.

Comment: This is amazing! exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot. My only concern is how shall I use it? if it is right now set as <div class="container"><?php the_field('this_field'); ?></div><div class="clear"></div> where do I have to add that?

Comment: Try: `<?php echo force_balance_tags( get_the_field( 'this_field' ) ); ?>`